# Parse.dll 1.6.0 does not have a strong name

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

It appears Parse.dll and Parse.NetFx45.dll from the .net 4.5 package do not have a strong name.

I have also tried signing them with my .snk, but I still have this exception when launching my app:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Parse, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
 StackTrace:    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)
   at Parse.ParseClient.GetParseType(String name)
   at Parse.ParseClient..cctor()
```

I have followed this guide to sign it personally: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx
But it does not work.

When showing properties of the said dlls in visual studio, it does say they have a strong name.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To people coming across this problem, the issue was reported to the Parse developers and they have fixed it.

Happy codding folks :)